# "Не могу написать, когда"

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис

Каким образом выделить, что я не могу написать именно "когда" что-то произойдет?
Например: *Извини, я сегодня не успею встретиться. 
Но и заранее пока не могу написать, когда.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Здесь не ставится запятая, поскольку неполное придаточное усечено до единственного союзного слова. 
(Розенталь: http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/49.htm §107, примечание 2в)
Если автору важно выделить это слово, можно предложить кавычки.

Answer (score 0):

Выделяется это постановкой ударения или штифтом (жирным, курсивом...). Квыфчки я бы не рекомендовал, они могут быть неправильно поняты - особенно в сочетании со словам "сказать".

---

Но тут другое интересно. Речь именно о той самой запятой, которая вроде бы и не имеет права тут находиться. 
Вот мне кажется, что как авторский знак ("интонационная запятая") она может быть использована именно для передачи логического ударения. 
У Розенталя это правило сформулировано, на мой взгляд, излишне прямолинейно. Тут ведь надо понимать, почему эта запятая по правилам не ставится. Дело в том, что союзное слово без присоединяемой части традиционно рассматривается как член не придаточного, а главного предложения. То есть придаточного как такового просто нет - отсюда нет и запятой. А при необходимости интонационно выделить это слово, оно как бы перестаёт быть членом главного - и становится самостоятельным придаточным.

Конечно, я не могу рекомендовать эту новацию для использования в серьезных текстах, требующих четкого соблюдения пунктуационных правил. Но в беллетристике... Я бы рискнул